# How to extract characters between the delimiters using sed?

Tags: linux, scripting, sed

I have just started learning sed. I want to extract and print the characters between the > and < delimiters. Here the text in my data file:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblRollNo">12029</span>

   <br /><b>Engineering & IT/Computer Science</b><br />

        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divEngITMerit">

                        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblEngITSelListNo">3rd Provisional Selection List</span>

                <tr><td style='width: 200px' class='TblTRData'>IT/Computer Science/Software</td><td style='width: 150px'class='TblTRData'>7 (out of 471)</td><td style='width: 325px'class='TblTRData'>Selected in MS COMPUTER SCIENCE</td></tr>

                                Name:

                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblName">SIDRA SHAHID</span>

                                Father Name:

                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblFatherName">SHAHID RAFEEQ AHMAD</span>
```

I have written the command:

```
sed -n -e '/^[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*/s//\1/p' myfile.txt
```

The problem is that it is returning the text between some of the > <. For example, it prints **12029**, but not Selected in **Selected in MS COMPUTER SCIENCE**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use an xml parser instead. What if you have entities thereinside?

Comment: I'll just drop this link into the comments in case anyone happens to find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract only strings between tags, this means you need to delete tags leaving strings between them untouched. Right?

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

It substitutes (all occurrences) of tag ( "<" everything upon next ">" ) with empty string (nothing). Text will remain.

Answer (score 0):

In sed, the `s` command has a `g` flag to operate on all pattern occurrences on a same line.

```
s/>\([^<]*\)</\1/pg
```

might suffice.

Comment: @mainajaved: and with this regex?

Comment: @mainajavaed : Unless your sed script is invoked with the `-n` option, you might try removing the 'p' at the end of that command. it means print, so any time you have a successful match the line is printed, which, if you don't have the `-n` option, can lead to some confusing output. BUT more importantly, per the link from Johnsweb and Benoit's original comment parsing XML with any reg-ex tool will never have any long term sucess. If as you say you're trying to learn sed, this is **really** not the sort of topic to start learning with.  Good luck.