# sed extract every occurrence of string between specific delimiters

Tags: string, sed, character, extract, delimiter

How to extract characters between delimiters ":" for all occurrences in a line (defined as strings separated by white-space) for all lines? 
I have tried  sed 's/.*:(.*):.*//g' but that doesn't take into account multiple occurrences.

given:

```
1/1:2.000:0.000,0.000,1.000 0/1:1.001:0.000,0.999,0.001
1/1:2.000:0.000,0.000,1.000 0/1:1.002:0.000,0.998,0.002
```

to be obtained:

```
2.000 1.001
2.000 1.002
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract characters between the delimiters using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684729/how-to-extract-characters-between-the-delimiters-using-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^:]*:([^:]*):\S*(\s)*/\1\2/g' file
```